# form w #ajax attribute to change content based on keyword input to be called to query Json from youtube

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am a PHP developer but new to Drupal development, although I am creating a module. Seen here http://vperry.co/drupal-aif-14/
I have created  block that is displaying Json from Youtube, using a query string w the getcontents function (php)
Here are my files on github.
https://github.com/aloysiusbe/aspenyoutube
I need to create a keyword input to work in drupal to pass a variable to send along with the Json query.
Here you can see with the regular php file it works:

Please Help!

Comment: I could not post that last link for regular php

Comment: http://vperry.co/YT-Json/26.php